# SAML workflow question regarding certificates

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, x509certificate

I have a question regarding saml workflow when certificates are being requested from the SP.

We are a SP and have implemented sso using saml for a number of customers. We send a standard request (doesn't include any certificate, or request isnt signed) to the clients IDP and handle their response validating their x509 cert which was shared pre-release and have installed on our server.

This is the only work we do with certificates at the moment. We now have a client who is asking for our x509 cert. We currently dont have a certificate, and i'm wondering what changes in our current workflow based on this request.

Do we need to sign our initial response or add the certificate into the body of the response? I'm a little in the dark to whats required from our end and what changes were going have to make.

It clearly is adding some other layer of security but could someone explain the workflow when this extra signing is used ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want to encrypt the SAML Response containing attribute statements, etc. They would use your public key (i.e. the SP's certificate) to encrypt the payload, and then you (as the holder of the SP's private key) would be the only one that could decrypt that content.

This is a perfectly reasonable request from the IdP.

And realistically, you *should* be signing your AuthnRequests and LogoutRequests with a certificate. You don't need to provide the encryption cert in the AuthnRequest, the IdP will use the cert in the metadata to encrypt the content.